# React Native Image Position

Tags: react-native

Is there a way how to control image position with `resizeMode` set to `cover`? I'm looking for similar result as can be achieve by using `background-positon: center bottom` in traditional CSS.

Here is an illustration of the situation:

1. Image with same dimensions as screen
2. Image with custom height, picture gets centered
3. (Desired) Image with custom height, but with picture aligned to the bottom edge of the element

[image]

My code:

`<Image 
    source={require('./eifell.jpg')} 
    resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover} 
    style={{
        height: 300
    }}
/>`

Comment: are you sure with the numbering? you really want to achieve nr.3 in your picture, where the picture is out of frame?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll have to achieve this by using the `transforms` prop on the image style and utilize the `translateY` transformation.

It will involve a little math... off the top of my head I believe you would need to follow these steps:

1. Use Image.getSize() to find the dimensions of your image
2. Then based on the size of your window from `Dimensions.get('window')` calculate how many pixels your image will scale to.
3. Find the difference between the height displayed (say 667px) and the desired height of the image (300px in your example)
4. Then translate the image up that many pixels.